# Downloading QGIS 3.22 LTR as exe file

Tags: qgis, installation

The latest MSI of QGIS 3.22 LTR is not accepted by Microsoft Intune, so I need an `*.exe` package to convert it to an intune file. Where can I find this `*.exe` for download?

Comment: open ticket about Intune/QGIS  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/49365

Answer (score -1):

From this website one can download QGIS `*.exe` files:

https://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/?C=N&O=A

Comment: Only of older versions than 3.22, not what was asked.